# Isolate vocal by removing background music

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I want to isolate vocal and remove the background music in an mp3 file. I don't need to get rid of background music completely but at least minimize it.

I tried `pydub` which helps with audio manipulation. I tried this code which REMOVES vocal and KEEPS background music. I need to do the opposite. I tried switching sound mono channels and inverting the other channel and that didn't work either.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

# read in audio file and get the two mono tracks
sound_stereo = AudioSegment.from_file(myAudioFile, format="mp3")
sound_monoL = sound_stereo.split_to_mono()[0]
sound_monoR = sound_stereo.split_to_mono()[1]

# Invert phase of the Right audio file
sound_monoR_inv = sound_monoR.invert_phase()

# Merge two L and R_inv files, this cancels out the centers
sound_CentersOut = sound_monoL.overlay(sound_monoR_inv)

# Export merged audio file
fh = sound_CentersOut.export(myAudioFile_CentersOut, format="mp3")
```

Does anyone know what the solution is for this? Thanks!

Comment: In general, there is no easy way to isolate vocals.  Look at the [Audacity manual](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_vocal_removal_and_isolation.html) for a possible technique.

Answer (score 2):

If your `sound_CentersOut` already have the vocals removed, why don't you apply a phase cancellation on your `sound_stereo` using an inverted form of `sound_CentersOut`?

```
# invert sound_CentersOut
sound_CentersOut_inv = sound_CentersOut.invert_phase()

# phase cancellation on original stereo with inverted sound_CentersOut
# the vocals should remain
vocals = sound_stereo.overlay(sound_CentersOut_inv)
```

Note that most songs will have vocals and bass in the center for presence so you may also have bass included with your vocals. If you really want to get surgical, you may have to do some EQ-ing to filter out the lower frequencies.

Comment: That didn't work for me. It gives me both vocal and background music and I didn't notice any difference between the original and the new output. When vocals are removed, they are almost completely removed and you can only hear the music but when I try phase cancellation on stereo, can't see the difference.

Comment: How about converting the stereo to mono first before applying the phase cancellation? `sound_mono = sound_stereo.set_channels(1)`. Then `vocals = sound_mono.overlay(sound_CentersOut_inv)`

Comment: thanks but that didn't work either. its hard to understand how you can isolate the background music but same method doesn't let you isolate vocal. i might be missing something..

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't know what other options there are. If you have the instrumental version of the song, you could invert the instrumentals and then overlay that on the original song.

Comment: thank you anyways. im just using ffmpeg filters to overcome the issue as much as i can.